# How to replicate and make transformations of rows in a BigQuery table using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in BQ that looks like this:

| Name | city | Gender | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | Denver | M | 2021-01-11 |
| David | Atlanta | M | 2021-01-11 |
| Darcy | NY | F | 2021-01-11 |

I need to replicate the initial rows multiple times, adding one day at a time to the Date column and appending all the new rows to the table. After running the query I need something like this:

| Name | city | Gender | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | Denver | M | 2021-01-11 |
| David | Atlanta | M | 2021-01-11 |
| Darcy | NY | F | 2021-01-11 |
| Alan | Denver | M | **2021-01-12** |
| David | Atlanta | M | **2021-01-12** |
| Darcy | NY | F | **2021-01-12** |
| Alan | Denver | M | **2021-01-13** |
| David | Atlanta | M | **2021-01-13** |
| Darcy | NY | F | **2021-01-13** |

I need to do this for a dataset with a lot of columns and rows and a lot of times, not just twice like the example. I started with something like this:

```
FOR record IN
  (SELECT *
   FROM `dataset.my_table`)
DO
  INSERT `dataset.my_table`  
  SELECT * EXCEPT(date),
      DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date
      FROM dataset.my_table
      where city = record.city 
      limit 1;
END FOR;
```

I used the `where city = record.city` and the `limit 1` statements to try to make the transformation on the same column for that loop (current record) but as you must been thinking this does not work well because sometimes it takes an already transformed row in the same for loop because a lot of rows are the same.

Thanks in advance if you have any suggestions about the query to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate a row by cross-joining with flattened date array like below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'Alan' Name,  'Denver' city,  'M' Gender, DATE '2021-01-11' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'David' Name, 'Atlanta' city, 'M' Gender, DATE '2021-01-11' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Darcy' Name, 'NY' city,      'F' Gender, DATE '2021-01-11' Date
)
SELECT t.* EXCEPT(date), date 
  FROM sample_table t, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date, date + 2)) date;

--Query results
+-------+---------+--------+------------+
| Name  |  city   | Gender |    date    |
+-------+---------+--------+------------+
| Alan  | Denver  | M      | 2021-01-11 |
| Alan  | Denver  | M      | 2021-01-12 |
| Alan  | Denver  | M      | 2021-01-13 |
| David | Atlanta | M      | 2021-01-11 |
| David | Atlanta | M      | 2021-01-12 |
| David | Atlanta | M      | 2021-01-13 |
| Darcy | NY      | F      | 2021-01-11 |
| Darcy | NY      | F      | 2021-01-12 |
| Darcy | NY      | F      | 2021-01-13 |
+-------+---------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jay! The only problem is that I have to do this for a lot of rows (2MM+) and I have to replicate the data for over 1080 days. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Not sure what's the purpose of the replication but if you want the replication for 1080 days, you can divide days into several periods and apply the above query to insert the output into date-partitioned tables.